# Alternative to the Mac window switcher "contexts"

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, software-rec, compiz

I'm trying to get on board with linux as my main daily driver, and I have just about everything set up to feel really well at this point. The one thing I don't have which has become an integral part of my flow on Mac OS, is an alternative to [Contexts](https://contexts.co/). Contexts lets you open the program with a global hotkey, then quickly switch to a different open window by typing in its name.

On Windows there's [Switcheroo](https://github.com/kvakulo/Switcheroo), and [Switchblade](https://www.switchbladeapp.com/) which are fairly similar, but I can't seem to find anything for Linux that lets you just type the window that you want to open.

I'm using vanilla Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to stumble upon something that's exactly what I'm looking for: [Switcher](https://github.com/daniellandau/switcher). As far as I can tell, Switcher functions identically to Contexts and matches its appearance pretty closely too (app icon next to text).

Answer (score 1):

You should give [Rofi](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi/) a try. It's an open-source launcher and window switcher.

There are also [Albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/) and [Cerebro](https://github.com/KELiON/cerebro), but these are more like Spotlight and don't support window switching.

Comment: Oh, Rofi looks really promising. I ended up going with Switcher, but really appreciate the response. Rofi looks like a good option if I want a bit more customization down the road.

Comment: Rofi is really good, and very customizable as well, and I just learned that it can be installed on Mac as well using Macports

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it, but would [SuperSwitcher](https://code.google.com/archive/p/superswitcher/) be along the lines of what you're looking for?